# On the Quote "We Have No Other Business Here Than to Get to Heaven"

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, saint

I would like to make use of a quote which I paraphrase here as follows: *``We have no other business here than to get to Heaven. Everything else is a waste of time.''*

I think that it (or something like it) had been uttered by a Catholic Saint, or at least by someone beatified in the Catholic Church.

Does anyone recollect which Saint said this, what the exact quote is, and where I may fine it? Thank you.

Comment: It was "St.  Vincent de Paul who said it. Here: https://saintquotes.tumblr.com/post/124812336522/our-business-is-to-gain-heaven-everything-else-is I have a couple of quotes that I like but I don't know who said them. "A Christians calling is other people."  And, "Give me souls or I'll die."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> “Our business is to gain heaven; everything else is a sheer waste of
> time.” - St. Vincent De Paul

Source: https://saintquotes.tumblr.com/post/124812336522/our-business-is-to-gain-heaven-everything-else-is

Comment: That seems to be it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

On page 36 of "Spirit of the Curé of Ars" (Catechism on Salvation):

https://ia803207.us.archive.org/14/items/TheSpiritOfTheCureOfArs/TheSpiritOfTheCureOfArs.pdf

is found the very similar quote (since to know, love, and serve God implies salvation, which in turn, implies getting to Heaven):

"To be saved, we must know, love, and serve God. Oh, what a beautiful life! How good, how great a thing it is to know, to love and serve God! We have nothing else to do in this world. All that we do besides is lost time."

And so, analogously to the St. Vincent de Paul quote---

> We have nothing else to do in this world. All that we do besides is lost time.

Perhaps, St. John Vianney spent some time reading St. Vincent de Paul.